# compile a program including cppunit with g ++

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, g++, cppunit

I'm on a project where I need to include the library automatic, cppunit tests. 
I need to compile the project with g ++ and not include the library as the compilation command

```
g ++ -Wall main.cc xx.cc xx.h test.cc xx-xx-test.h
```

I also do not know the path where the libraries installed linux system.

Anyone who knows the subject, will help

library: cppunit-1.13.2 
compiler: g++

Comment: I am not sure what you want. A tutorial? What is your problem? Please try to follow expected question/answer format.

Comment: hi , thanks for comment  I need the line c ++ compile a program including a library...
for example:
g++ main.c -o test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ *.cc *.h -lcppunit -o test

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: ok men, but this line is the answer , sorry for my bad english.